# Powershell sort command not working as expected

Tags: powershell, sorting, windows-10

I used this set of commands to check the sort command on the keyboard characters.

```
$symb="a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","²","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","°","+","&","é",'"',"'","(","-","è",[regex]::escape('`'),"_","ç","à",")","=","~","#","{","[","|","\","^","@","]","}","$","¨","ˆ","£","¤","ù","*","%","µ","<",",",";",":","!",">","?",".","/","§","€"; $symb|sort|ac file.txt;(gc file.txt)-join""
```

Here is what I get, both in a file and on the console.

```
'-!"#$%&()*,./:;?@[\]ˆ^_`{|}~¨£¤€+<=>§°µ012²3456789aAàbBcCçDdEeéèfFgGhHIiJjKkLlmMNnOoPpqQRrsStTuUùvVwWXxyYzZ
```

In about half the cases of pairs  of lower- and uppercase letters the order is inverted; it seems it should always be "lowercase first, uppercase next". How can that be fixed?

Comment: Use the `CaseSensitive` parameter: `sort -CaseSensitive`. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object).

Comment: @kuujinbo It didn't occur to me at all that that was needed. Thanks, it works. You should turn your comment into an answer, there is no other way to add points to your account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PowerShell - unlike the .NET framework's types - is case-*insensitive* by default; you need to *opt in* if you want case-*sensitive* behavior.**

In the case of [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) you need to use its `-CaseSensitive` switch:

```
PS> -join ('a', 'B', 'A', 'b' | Sort-Object -CaseSensitive)
aAbB
```

As you expected, this results in *lowercase* letters sorting *first*, because in the (US-English) collation order lowercase letters have lower sorting weight than uppercase ones - even though with respect to their Unicode *code points* the relationship is reversed (e.g., `[int] [char] 'a'` is `97`, whereas `[int] [char] 'A'` is `65`).

(Code-point-based sorting would apply if the array contained `[char]` instances, but PowerShell has no `[char]` literals, so a literal such as `'a'` is a `[string]` of length `1`; you can use explicit casts, however: 
 `-join ([char] 'A', [char] 'a' | Sort-Object -CaseSensitive)` yields `'Aa'`, i.e. sorts *uppercase* first.)

---

**Without `-CaseSensitive`, the lowercase and uppercase variants of a given letter have equal sorting weight, so no particular ordering among them is guaranteed.**

For instance, the following loop exits quickly:

```
$prevResult = $null
while ($true) { 

  # Get a shuffled array of lower- and uppercase letters.
  $arr = 'a', 'B', 'A', 'b'
  $arr = $arr | Get-Random -Count $arr.Count

  # Sort it case-INsensitively.
  $result = -join ($arr | Sort-Object)

  $result # output

  # See if the result is different from the previous one.
  # Note the use of -cne rather than just -ne:
  # -ce is the case-*sensitive* variant of -ne
  if ($prevResult -and $prevResult -cne $result) {
    Write-Warning "Output order has changed."
    break
  }
  $prevResult = $result

}
```

However, note that `Sort-Object` appears to perform a *stable* sort: that is, with a given input array the resulting array is always the same.
That is, if you move the creation of `$arr` outside the `while` loop, the result is always the same and the loop never exits.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @LPH; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

The .net way does not have this problem.

```
$symb = "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "²", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "°", "+", "&", "é", '"', "'", "(", "-", "è", [regex]::escape('`'), "_", "ç", "à", ")", "=", "~", "#", "{", "[", "|", "\", "^", "@", "]", "}", "$", "¨", "ˆ", "£", "¤", "ù", "*", "%", "µ", "<", ",", ";", ":", "!", ">", "?", ".", "/", "§", "€"; 
[Array]::Sort($symb)
$symb
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. Do you have any idea of what the problem would be?

Comment: No but since Powershell is case insensitive about everywhere, I assume their implementation of Sort is some respect the same and does behave indifferently in-between Uppser / Lower case, leading to some inconsistency there... 

That's just assumption based though. 
Their implementation is here : https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/Sort-Object.cs (although things might have been fixed in the current code for PS7)